# RoR select tag options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, helper, formhelper

My model is given below

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  ANSWERS= ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3', 'Option 4']
end
```

In the view `<%= select(:question, :answer, Question::ANSWERS, {:include_blank => true}) %>` outputs

```
<select name="question[answer]" id="question_answer">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

I tried `<%= select(:question, :answer, Question::ANSWERS.collect {|d| [d, Question::ANSWERS.index(d)]}, {:include_blank => true}) %>` 
This yields

```
<select name="question[answer]" id="question_answer">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="0">Option 1</option>
  <option value="1">Option 2</option>
  <option value="2">Option 3</option>
  <option value="3">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

But I need the following output

```
<select name="question[answer]" id="question_answer">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second example, use:

```
<%= select(:question, 
           :answer, 
           Question::ANSWERS.collect {|d| [d, Question::ANSWERS.index(d) + 1]},
           {:include_blank => true}) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can little modify your array with key value pair of hash like this

```
ANSWERS= [1=>'Option 1', 2=>'Option 2', 3=>'Option 3', 4=>'Option 4']
```

Now use options_for_select and get desired output.